# Myclass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource() return empty path

Tags: java, eclipse, path, jvm, executable-jar

i'm trying to find the location of the running jar file using the method:

```
File jarFile = new File(JarPath.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI());
```

when i run it on the IDE (eclipse) it returns the correct path.
but when i run the jar as an executable the code source returned is

```
rsrc:./
```

ideas on how the get the correct path?

Comment: I have the same problem, so far I found out that this happens when you use the option "Package required libraries into generated JAR" when generating the jar in Eclipse.

Comment: No repo in NetBeans

Answer (score 3):

Try a different approach to get the location.

```
String jarFilePath = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(".")
        .toURI()
        .getPath()
        .replaceFirst("/", "");
```

This gives you up to the parent location of the jar file.

```
C:/Users/Roshana Pitigala/Desktop/
```

You still need to add the filename and the extension (`jarFileName.jar`).

Comment: Don’t use the class loader when looking up a class’ resources. This can break as soon as modules are involved, as that information is missing. You can use `JarPath.class.getResource("JarPath.class")`, which is simpler than `JarPath.class.getClassLoader().getResource(JarPath.class.getName().replace('.', '/') + ".class")` and works in a modular environment, as still having the `Class` implies knowing the associated module.

Comment: This does not work. The `getPath()` throws a `NullPointerException`, and the `toURI()` gives the fully qualified class name, not the path to the jar!

Comment: @user7291698 try now. I've updated the answer as Holger suggested. Btw upto `getPath()` it should return the path to the class not the jar. The idea is to get the path to the class and remove the unnecessary parts.

Comment: Your solution only works when you create the jar using the Eclipse option "Extract required libraries into generated JAR". But I need a solution that works with the option "Package required libraries into generated JAR"!

Comment: @user7291698 Check the answer now. It's tested, and working.

Comment: Great, now it works, thank you! I will give you the bounty, but would appreciate an additional hint how to get the name of the jar-file itself, in case the user renames the jar-file.

Comment: @user7291698 yeah, I'll keep trying and update the answer as soon as I find a solution.